How to pass DismissAction in swift ui
I am making simple task manager app. There is main view where the action will be displayed.
//
//  MainView.swift
//  IOS
//
//  Created by Simone Samardzhiev on 14.05.24.
//

import SwiftUI

/// The main view of the app.
struct MainView: View {
    /// Manager of the tasks.
    @StateObject var taskManager = TaskManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader() { geo in
            NavigationStack {
                VStack {
                    TaskScrollView (
                        width: geo.size.width,
                        height: geo.size.height / 2
                    )
                    
                    SaveTaskButton (
                        width: geo.size.width / 2,
                        height: geo.size.height / 15
                    )
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        NavigationLink {
                            AddTaskView()
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }

                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Tasks")
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(taskManager)
    }
}

As you can see the AddTaskView() is used in a navigation link so when you click the button it will be shown.
Here is the AddTaskView struct.
//
//  AddTaskView.swift
//  IOS
//
//  Created by Simone Samardzhiev on 15.05.24.
//

import SwiftUI

/// Views used to add a task.
struct AddTaskView: View {
    /// Variable keeping the name of the task.
    @State var name: String = ""
    /// Variable keeping the explanation of the task.
    @State var explanation: String = ""
    /// Variable keeping the explanation of the task.
    @State var importance: Importances = .insignificant
    /// Action used to dismiss the view when needed.
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    /// Manager of the tasks.
    @EnvironmentObject var taskManager: TaskManager
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader() { geo in
            VStack {
                NameEditor (
                    width: geo.size.width / 1.2,
                    height: geo.size.height / 12,
                    name: $name
                )
                
                ExplanationEditor (
                    width: geo.size.width / 1.2,
                    height: geo.size.height / 3,
                    explanation: $explanation
                )
                
                ImportancePicker (
                    importance: $importance
                )
                
                AddTaskButton (
                    width: geo.size.width / 2,
                    height: geo.size.height / 15,
                    name: name,
                    explanation: explanation,
                    importance: importance
                )
            }
            .navigationTitle("Add task")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}

The only problem I have I that when the AddTaskButton() is clicked I want the view to be closed and get back to the main view. You can do that using the dismiss variable. The only problem is that I can't pass that variable to the AddTaskButton().
I tried passing it as a binding variable but that did't work. I also tried to put it in .environment() to the AddTaskButton(), but that did't also work. I tried passing it as a function that the result wasn't successful. So how can I pass that variable to a subview or its impossible.

Can't you just read the environment in AddTaskButton, in the same way you read it in AddTaskView? Please show a [mcve] - something I can copy and paste into a new Xcode project and reproduce your problem.

Unrelated but it's highly recommended to declare all @State variables as private.

You could try a different approach to achieve ...when the AddTaskButton() is clicked I want the view to be closed,
using
AddTaskButton(...)
    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded { dismiss() }) // <-- here

